# React Router Redirect state is undefined when used in Protected Route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

In my React Project I defined protected route like below. In which I am trying to pass user accessed URL to Redirect state property, so that I can navigate the URL after successful navigation.

When I print the URL in Protected route I see correct value, but when I try to access it in Login component I get state `undefined`. I have looked at many StackOverFlow issues and articles, nothing helped me so far

**ReadOnlyAccessGuardedRoute.tsx**

```
export function ReadOnlyAccessGuardedRoute(props: { component: any; path: string; isAuthorized: boolean, exact: boolean }) {
    const {component: Component, path, exact, isAuthorized, ...rest} = props;
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(routeProps) =>
                <div>
                    {/* If not logged in, redirect to Login page */}
                    <ReactIf condition={!AuthService.isLoggedIn()}>
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: '/login',
                                state: {from: routeProps.location}
                            }}
                        />
                    </ReactIf>

                    {/* If logged in and has Read Only User role, navigate to component */}
                    <ReactIf condition={isAuthorized}>
                        <Component {...routeProps} />
                    </ReactIf>
                </div>
            }
        />
    );
}
```

**Login.tsx**

```
export default function Login(): JSX.Element {
    const location = useLocation();
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('location',location);
    }, [])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I was actually overwriting the state in **App.tsx**. Changing the line `history.push("/login");` to `history.push("/login", location?.pathname);` preserves the state.

```
export default function App(): JSX.Element {

    const history = useHistory();
    const location = useLocation();

    //ReactIf user not logged in, redirect to Login page
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!AuthService.isUserLoggedIn()) {
            AuthService.setCookie(new Cookie("redirectUrl", location?.pathname ?? '/', 3600000, '/'));
            history.push("/login", location?.pathname);
        }
    }, [history, location?.pathname])
.........
```

Answer (score 0):

I just recreated your `ReadOnlyAccessGuardedRoute` component as follow:

```
export function ReadOnlyAccessGuardedRoute(props: {
  component: any;
  path: string;
  isAuthorized: boolean;
  exact: boolean;
}) {
  const { component: Component, path, exact, isAuthorized, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(routeProps) => (
        <div>
          {AuthService.isLoggedIn ? (
            <Component {...routeProps} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: { from: routeProps.location }
              }}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

and then in `login.tsx` you can use `this.props.location.state.from` to   get the state.

here is **code sandbox** link for more clarification: https://codesandbox.io/s/private-route-vmrxs?file=/src/privateRoute.tsx